# ios AVFoundation - how to deal with UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp and UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I'm using AVFoundationFramework to capture video. When I starting capturing I set video orientation based on current device orientation. I do it like this:

```
startRecordingOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
AVCaptureVideoOrientation avcaptureOrientation;
if ( startRecordingOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft )
{
    avcaptureOrientation  = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
else if ( startRecordingOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight )
{
    avcaptureOrientation  = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
else if(startRecordingOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
{
    avcaptureOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
}
else if(startRecordingOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    avcaptureOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
}

[videoConnection setVideoOrientation:avcaptureOrientation];
```

But I have problem with UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp and UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown. I need to know what is device oriention to properly set recording video orientation becouse If I don't do that my video output will be rotated. I can't use InterfaceOrientation instead of AVCaptureVideoOrientation becouse my application use only portrait orientation. Is there any way to determine if iOS device is in exactly portrait/landscape orientation? If not, I can load my recorded video and then determine video orientation and rotate it to portrait but is there any way to determine orientation of already recorded video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp and UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown haven't a corresponding interface rotation, by default you can match the orientation that you prefer, I use portrait.